# How to get BiFunction working for configureExecutionInput WebGraphQlInterceptor from spring-graphql documentation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-graphql

I am trying to use following code snippet from the [spring-graphql documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.1.3/reference/html/#server.interception.web)

```
class RequestHeaderInterceptor implements WebGraphQlInterceptor { 

    @Override
    public Mono<WebGraphQlResponse> intercept(WebGraphQlRequest request, Chain chain) {
        String value = request.getHeaders().getFirst("myHeader");
        request.configureExecutionInput((executionInput, builder) ->
                builder.graphQLContext(Collections.singletonMap("myHeader", value)).build());
        return chain.next(request);
    }
}
```

I am getting following compilation error on the line:

```
request.configureExecutionInput((executionInput, builder)
```

Error:

> The method configureExecutionInput(BiFunction<ExecutionInput,ExecutionInput.Builder,ExecutionInput>) in the type DefaultExecutionGraphQlRequest is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> executionInput,
> <no type> builder) -> {})

How to use ExecutionInput and Builder?

Updates:

I am using following tech stack:

- Java17
- Spring Boot 3.0.5

Following are the dependencies in my maven pom:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
        <artifactId>graphql-kickstart-spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        <version>11.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: you need an extra closed paranthesis at the end `.build()));`